# Camera rotation and orientation in variable gravity

Tags: c++, camera, orientation, physics

I'm attempting to implement a camera controller for a first person, mouse-look based camera for OpenGL. This is a simple problem when the camera is always oriented normally (camera up vector = world Y axis). However, I'm having real trouble getting everything working properly with a camera that can be used seamlessly for any orientation. The purpose is to allow a player to move around an entire planet. An additional requirement is that the direction remain the same relative to the orientation as the camera's orientation changes. An example would be, if you're walking around a planet, the direction remains the same relative to the ground, so as you go "down" along the side from a pole, the direction is also automatically rotated.

So far, I've attempted a number of different things to get this working, but as I see it, there should be two different ways of doing this. The first is to do regular camera rotation based on yaw and pitch angles from the world axes, and then transform the resulting look direction by the camera orientation to obtain the final look direction. The second approach is to rotate the camera with yaw and pitch angles based on calculated up and right vectors. The up vector is easy here; it's just the orientation. I haven't gotten any right vector I've found to work correctly though.

OK, here's the code for these two approaches.

**Common code**

```
// m_orientation calculated from planet center to current position
m_horizontal += horizontal;
m_vertical += vertical;

while (m_horizontal > TWO_PI) {
    m_horizontal -= TWO_PI;
}

while (m_horizontal < -TWO_PI) {
    m_horizontal += TWO_PI;
}

if (m_vertical > MAX_VERTICAL) {
    m_vertical = MAX_VERTICAL;
}
else if (m_vertical < -MAX_VERTICAL) {
    m_vertical = -MAX_VERTICAL;
}

// code from either implementation

m_view = glm::lookAt(m_position, m_position + m_direction, m_orientation);
```

**First approach** with yaw, pitch about world axes and then transform

```
// check for m_orientation != WORLD_UP...
glm::vec3 axis = glm::normalize(glm::cross(WORLD_UP, m_orientation));
float angle_degrees = acosf(m_orientation.y) * RADS_TO_DEGREES;
glm::mat4 trans = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), angle_degrees, axis);

// can also be determined with two rotation matrices about world axes, end result is identical
m_direction = glm::vec3(cosf(m_vertical) * sinf(m_horizontal),
                        sinf(m_vertical),
                        cosf(m_vertical) * cosf(m_horizontal));
m_direction = glm::vec3(trans * glm::vec4(m_direction));
```

**Second approach** with yaw and pitch about appropriate up and right vectors

```
m_right = ??? // tried literally everything
glm::mat4 yaw = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), m_horizontal, m_orientation);
glm::mat4 pitch = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), m_vertical, m_right);
glm::mat4 trans = yaw * pitch;
m_direction = glm::vec3(trans[2]); // z axis
```

OK, so here's the problem. The first approach works almost perfectly, but near the south pole of a planet (within ~15 degrees of orientation=(0,-1,0), effect gets stronger closer you are), the camera is automatically rotated toward the south pole as the orientation changes. So if the camera orientation does not change, near the south pole, the camera works perfectly. Any change in orientation results in the camera rotating toward the south pole. The more orientation change, the more the camera rotates. Now I have tried removing either the pitch or yaw from the world axis camera rotation, and this effect appears only with the pitch calculation included. With only yaw, then the camera behaves perfectly (lacking any pitch control ofc). As far as I can tell, *my transformation to go from regular up=(0,1,0) to the current orientation is incorrect*. Any help on that?

Now the other way to do things appears to work somewhat correctly, but I simply have not found a good right vector. Everything I've tried results in strange behavior of both horizontal and vertical movements. The most obvious solution, cross product of previous frame's direction and current orientation to produce the right vector doesn't work. Any suggestions for a good right vector?

I'm also happy to see completely different solutions to this problem. I know it's possible, but no amount of searching has given me a good solution. Thanks very much in advance.

Edit 1: Tried a few more things in response to Paweł Stawarz

Results in incorrect orientation of camera and weird mouse movement. I made sure my matrix multiplication was in the correct order. I also tried the transpose.

```
m_view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), m_direction, m_up);
m_view = trans * m_view; //trans is rotation from orientation=(0,1,0) to orientation=m_orientation
```

Results in the same problem as previously, with the camera rotating toward the south pole by itself. Also the vertical mouse rotation is not correct, causes camera to go in circles.

```
m_view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), m_direction, m_up);
m_view = trans * m_view;
m_direction = glm::vec3(m_view[2]);

m_view = glm::lookAt(m_position, m_direction + m_position, m_orientation);
```

Edit 2: Using the RIGHT vector method, with no transformation between orientations is working a little better. However, it causes the camera yaw to oscillate wildly with pitch near to vertical (at least 5 degrees away from vertical). In addition, the range of motion for pitch is not adjusted by the orientation, so for example on the side of the planet, vertical motion is restricted to directly in front of you to behind you (~(0,1,0) to ~(0,-1,0)).

```
glm::mat4 yaw = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), m_horizontal * ONEEIGHTY_PI, m_orientation);
glm::mat4 pitch = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), m_vertical * -ONEEIGHTY_PI, m_right);

glm::mat4 cam = pitch * yaw;

m_right = glm::vec3(cam[0]);
m_up = glm::vec3(cam[1]);
m_direction = glm::vec3(cam[2]);

m_view = glm::lookAt(m_position, m_direction + m_position, m_up);
m_vp = m_perspective * m_view;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Needed a different transformation. See [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73588/how-do-i-fix-my-planet-facing-camera) for a pretty good explanation.

```
glm::mat4 trans;
float factor = 1.0f;
float real_vertical = vertical;
m_horizontal += horizontal;
m_vertical += vertical;

while (m_horizontal > TWO_PI) {
    m_horizontal -= TWO_PI;
}

while (m_horizontal < -TWO_PI) {
    m_horizontal += TWO_PI;
}

if (m_vertical > MAX_VERTICAL) {
    m_vertical = MAX_VERTICAL;
}
else if (m_vertical < -MAX_VERTICAL) {
    m_vertical = -MAX_VERTICAL;
}

glm::quat world_axes_rotation = glm::angleAxis(m_horizontal * ONEEIGHTY_PI, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
world_axes_rotation = glm::normalize(world_axes_rotation);
world_axes_rotation = glm::rotate(world_axes_rotation, m_vertical * ONEEIGHTY_PI, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

m_pole = glm::normalize(m_pole - glm::dot(m_orientation, m_pole) * m_orientation);

glm::mat4 local_transform;

local_transform[0] = glm::vec4(m_pole.x, m_pole.y, m_pole.z, 0.0f);
local_transform[1] = glm::vec4(m_orientation.x, m_orientation.y, m_orientation.z, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 tmp = glm::cross(m_pole, m_orientation);
local_transform[2] = glm::vec4(tmp.x, tmp.y, tmp.z, 0.0f);
local_transform[3] = glm::vec4(m_position.x, m_position.y, m_position.z, 1.0f);

world_axes_rotation = glm::normalize(world_axes_rotation);
m_view = local_transform * glm::mat4_cast(world_axes_rotation);
m_direction = -1.0f * glm::vec3(m_view[2]);
m_up = glm::vec3(m_view[1]);
m_right = glm::vec3(m_view[0]);

m_view = glm::inverse(m_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we keep things simple, by using the standard approach:

1. Move the camera to the current player position
2. Rotate it towards where the player is looking at

The camera rotation is described by:

- The UP vector which is the normalized vector that starts at `(p0x,p0y,p0z)` (where `p0` is the position of the center of planet) and goes thru `(p1x,p1y,p1z)` (where `p1` describes the place the player is currently at),
- the RIGHT vector is the vector perpendicular to the UP vector **and** perpendicular to the direction the player is looking - the LOOK vector (in the case where he's looking straight ahead - perpendicular to his direction).

Since the UP vector can be calulated straight from the player current position, you have to get the LOOK and RIGHT vectors. Both are cross products of [corresponding other vectors](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/142067-up-and-right-vector/).

Note also, that allowing the player to look up/down and pan his head, can (and probably will) in fact change the UP vector.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the UP and RIGHT vectors, but my problem is more complex. I have tried using the cross product of the LOOK (from the previous frame) and UP vectors for the RIGHT vector, but it didn't work: the horizontal and vertical movements of the mouse did not result in independent horizontal and vertical rotation of the camera when the orientation was not (0,1,0). I tried several variations as well, with no luck.

Comment: If you can manage to get the UP and LOOK vectors good, just call `lookAt()`. It should produce a transfomation matrix that reflects the player current direction (not the lookin direction, the direction of the player himself, the character). __After__ calling it, rotate the vision in the direction you want with `glRotatef` or other functions. That should produce the orientation of the players "head".

Comment: I haven't managed to get that working either. First of all, `lookAt()` also "bakes in" the camera's position, which you don't want if you're rotating it. Even when working off a position at the origin, there were a number of problems. I edited my post to describe them and put the code. Thanks

Comment: @moldyviolinist It doesn't "bake" the matrix. It forwards it to the openGL state machine. You can still overwrite it with `glLoadMatrix(glm::value_ptr(yourMatrixName))`. At least that's what the GLM manual says, since I'm only familiar with basic OpenGL and GLUT :)

Comment: I'm using OpenGL 3.3, not 2.x. GLM does not interact with OpenGL I don't believe. Do you have any ideas about the transformation matrix that is rotating the direction vector incorrectly when the orientation is close to (0,-1,0)? I just can't understand why it would do that, particularly if it doesn't occur in a similar fashion near (0,1,0).